# Alternate for `touchmove` in javascript event

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework

Alternate for `touchmove` in javascript event.
Once am using `touchmove` am getting a warning as follow.

```
'Touch.webkitRadiusX' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.radiusX' instead.
ionic.js:1155 'Touch.webkitRadiusY' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.radiusY' instead.
ionic.js:1155 'Touch.webkitRotationAngle' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.rotationAngle' instead.
ionic.js:1155 'Touch.webkitForce' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.force' instead.
```

Any help please.

Comment: Are you using ionic?

Comment: @NamPham yes am using ionic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Ionic Gesture to track various touch event like : `hold`, `tap`, `doubletap`, `drag`, `dragstart`, `dragend`, `dragup`, `dragdown`, `dragleft`, `dragright`, `swipe`, `swipeup`, `swipedown`, `swipeleft`, `swiperight`, `transform`, `transformstart`, `transformend`, `rotate`, `pinch`, `pinchin`, `pinchout`,
`touch`, `release`.

In your case, I think `touchmove` can be replaced with `drag` event. This event return the x, y for you.

This is how to use:

**In your controller:** Inject the `$ionicGesture` dependency.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$ionicGesture', function($ionicGesture){
    $ionicGesture.on('drag', function (e) {
        //Your logic here.
        //You can use console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)) to check the object (x,y coors)
    })
}]);
```

*More details at [Ionic Docs Site](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.EventController/)*

Comment: What is the android version that you're using?